# Retina sprites and high contrast mode

Tags: css, retina, high-contrast

So this is a tricky question I know. I've faced the issues with sprites and high contrast mode, basically it can be solved with code as follows:

```
.icon:before {
  content: url(icons.png);
  position:relative;
  left:-2px;
  top:-109px;
}

.icon {
  width:17px;
  height:18px;
  display:inline-block;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

That's nice. It does work. However, if I change the content url for retina, the image will be much much bigger and hence, it will fail.

Is there anyway to have the best of both worlds?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display your image the same way as non retina images, you need to set up the width of your image.

Here a some examples:

Here is an example with min-width (responsive design)
Desktop css:

```
.site-header {
    position: relative;
    background: url('assets/images/XXXX.jpg') 0px 0px no-repeat;
    height: 155px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position:center;
}
```

Retina on responsive design

```
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (min-width: 768px),
only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (min-width: 768px),
only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1)    and (min-width: 768px),
only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (min-width: 768px),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 192dpi) and (min-width: 768px),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 2dppx)  and (min-width: 768px) { 

 .site-header
    {
        position: relative;
        background: url('assets/images/GBBO_BG_1536_R.jpg') 0px 0px no-repeat;
        height: 148px;
        background-size:cover;
    } 

    /*  Iphone P */
    #header #logo_home {
        width: 154px;
        height: 102px;
        background: url('assets/images/GBBO_logo_1536_R.png') 0px 0px no-repeat;
        background-size: 100% auto;
                }
}
```

To remove the responsive effect, remove the  "and (min-width: 768px)"